# Add child view to titleView in navigation bar

Tags: swift

I tried to add a toolbar to the title view from navigation bar, so i added a container view to title View:

[image]

After that, i added toolButtons into the childVC, and changed class to ToolbarVC:
[image]

When i run the App, as the ParrentVC (TakingNoteVC) appears, the app got crashed with those error:
exception UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency

**Reason**: Child view controller:ToolBarVC should have parent view controller:UINavigationController but actual parent is TakingNoteVC

What am i doing wrong?